# Xamarin Forms StackLayout with two Frames not filling up the screen

Tags: xamarin.forms

I see a very strange behavior that I can't understand. I am putting two Frames inside vertically oriented StackLayout. The first Frames' Vertical Option is set to StartAndExpand which renders correctly but the Second Frames' VerticalOption is set to FillAndExpand and for some strange reason it does not follow after the first Frame but from the middle of the screen. I want the Second Frame to immediately follow after the first Frame and take up the whole screen. 
Code Below:

```
 <RelativeLayout 
        x:Name="mainLayout"         
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}"
        RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=1}">      
            <StackLayout 
                    Padding="5,5,5,5"
                    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    Orientation="Vertical"
                    Spacing="0"
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}"
                    RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=0.88}" >
                <Frame 
                    OutlineColor="Silver"
                    BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF"
                    VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                    HasShadow="False" >
                    <StackLayout 
                            BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                        <RelativeLayout
                            RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1}"
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            <Label 
                                x:Name="To_Label"
                                RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=0.2}"
                                RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=0}"
                                FontSize="Micro"
                                TranslationY="7"
                                FontAttributes="Bold"
                                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                TextColor="#2A84D3"
                                Text="To:">

                            </Label>
                            <Controls:DoneEntry x:Name="To_Entry"
                                    Text="{Binding Model.To}"
                                    RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=0.22}"
                                    RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=0.70}"
                                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
                                <CorcavBehaviors:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                    <CorcavBehaviors:BehaviorCollection>
                                        <PounceBehaviors:EntryTextChanged Command="{Binding ReceipientTextChangeCommand}"/>
                                    </CorcavBehaviors:BehaviorCollection>
                                </CorcavBehaviors:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            </Controls:DoneEntry>
                        </RelativeLayout>                        
                    </StackLayout>
                </Frame>
                <Frame 
                    OutlineColor="Silver"
                    BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF"
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    HasShadow="False" >
                    <StackLayout 
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                            BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                        <Editor 
                                Text="{Binding EmailContent}"
                                FontSize="Micro"
                                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                 >
                            <CorcavBehaviors:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                <CorcavBehaviors:BehaviorCollection>
                                    <PounceBehaviors:EditorTextChanged Command="{Binding MessageTextChangedCommand}"/>
                                </CorcavBehaviors:BehaviorCollection>
                            </CorcavBehaviors:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        </Editor>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Frame>

            </StackLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
                Padding="5,5,5,5"
                RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=.12}"
                RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1}"
                RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=0.88}"
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">

            <BoxView Color="#3E95D1" RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1}" HeightRequest="1" />

            <Controls:SwipeRightButton x:Name="SendEmail_Button"
                    BackgroundColor="#2A84D3"
                    OutlineColor="Silver"
                    HasShadow="False"
                    RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1}"
                    RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=0.90}" >

                <StackLayout x:Name="ImageLabelContainer"
                        RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=1}"
                        RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=0.90}"
                        Orientation="Horizontal"
                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">

                    <Image 
                            x:Name="connect_icon" 
                            Source="sendemailwhite"
                            Aspect="AspectFill"
                            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                            VerticalOptions="Center"
                            HorizontalOptions="Center">
                    </Image>
                    <Label 
                            VerticalOptions="Center"
                            HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                            FontSize="Micro"
                            TextColor="#FFFFFF"
                            Text="Swipe to Send" />
                </StackLayout>
            </Controls:SwipeRightButton>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. The first Frames' VerticalOption should be Start instead of StartAndExpand.